# Nginx is not loading my /_next/static/css folder and files

Tags: javascript, nginx, next.js, proxy, hosting

So, I have a **NextJS application** running in port 3000, and when I start this app after `npm run build` with `npm start` my application in port 3000 works perfectly, also if I check the *Source* section in my browser the `css` folder shows correctly.

[In localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBrQF.png)

But when I load the proxied server, in localhost:80, these folders (media and css) **are not showing up**, and the style of the website brokes.

[In localhost:80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnXwy.png)

I've tried using `include [...]/mime.types`, and proxying the _next directory, but this doesn't seem to work, I'm new to Nginx and web hosting so I'll be glad if anyone can help.

As I said, I've tried including the mime.types

This is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root D:/es12front/;

        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                return 204;
                access_log     off;
                log_not_found  off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                access_log off;
                include [...]/nginx-1.25.0/conf/mime.types;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any luck? I've been stuck on this issue for months. npm build works just fine, but nginx proxy is not loading the styles...